# Request Body List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have WebService with the following method's:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
string PostList(List<string> arr);
```

The RequestBody of the method is:

```
{"arr" : ["somestring1", "somestring2"]}
```

Now, I want another web method like that:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
string PostListKVP(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> arr);
```

How does the JSON RequestBody should be for this WebMethod?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't a dictionary work better than a list of key-value pairs?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko not if you are expecting duplicate keys :)

Comment: @vtortola, I'm not expected to duplicate keys but you are right..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dmytro Shevchenko suggest i replace to `Dictionary<string,string>` like the follow:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
string PostDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> arr);
```

And the requestbody is:

```
{"str" : [{"Key":1,"Value":2},{"Key":2,"Value":3}]}
```